# How to add theme to application using color picker dialog?

Tags: java, android, themes, android-theme, color-picker

I want to add themes to my application. For this I added color picker dialog.

When the user will select the color from color picker theme of the application should change, I want to change the color of navigation bar and floating button.

Like below images :

color picker dialog.
[image]

Changed theme on selected color :

[image]

For dialog I have followed this link : 
https://github.com/flavienlaurent/colorpicker

I have added color picker dialog :

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener {
    protected AlertDialog mAlertDialog;
    protected int[] mColors = null;
    protected int mColumns;
    protected ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener mListener;
    private ColorPickerPalette mPalette;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    protected int mSelectedColor;
    protected int mSize;
    protected int mTitleResId = R.string.color_picker_default_title;

    private void refreshPalette() {
        if ((this.mPalette != null) && (this.mColors != null))
            this.mPalette.drawPalette(this.mColors, this.mSelectedColor);
    }

    public void initialize(int titleId, int[] colors, int selectedColor, int columns, int size) {
        setArguments(titleId, columns, size);
        setColors(colors, selectedColor);
    }

    public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {
        if (this.mListener != null)
            this.mListener.onColorSelected(selectedColor);
        if ((getTargetFragment() instanceof ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener))
            ((ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener) getTargetFragment()).onColorSelected(selectedColor);
        if (selectedColor != this.mSelectedColor) {
            this.mSelectedColor = selectedColor;
            this.mPalette.drawPalette(this.mColors, this.mSelectedColor);
        }
        dismiss();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.mTitleResId = getArguments().getInt("title_id");
            this.mColumns = getArguments().getInt("columns");
            this.mSize = getArguments().getInt("size");
        }
        if (bundle != null) {
            this.mColors = bundle.getIntArray("colors");
            this.mSelectedColor = ((Integer) bundle.getSerializable("selected_color")).intValue();
        }
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.color_picker_dialog, null);
        this.mProgress = ((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(android.R.id.progress));
        this.mPalette = ((ColorPickerPalette) view.findViewById(R.id.color_picker));
        this.mPalette.init(this.mSize, this.mColumns, this);
        if (this.mColors != null)
            showPaletteView();
        this.mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle(this.mTitleResId).setView(view).create();
        return this.mAlertDialog;
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putIntArray("colors", this.mColors);
        bundle.putSerializable("selected_color", Integer.valueOf(this.mSelectedColor));
    }

    public void setArguments(int titleId, int columns, int size) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("title_id", titleId);
        bundle.putInt("columns", columns);
        bundle.putInt("size", size);
        setArguments(bundle);
    }

    public void setColors(int[] colors, int selected) {
        if ((this.mColors != colors) || (this.mSelectedColor != selected)) {
            this.mColors = colors;
            this.mSelectedColor = selected;
            refreshPalette();
        }
    }

    public void setOnColorSelectedListener(ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener onColorSelectedListener) {
        this.mListener = onColorSelectedListener;
    }

    public void showPaletteView() {
        if ((this.mProgress != null) && (this.mPalette != null)) {
            this.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            refreshPalette();
            this.mPalette.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void showProgressBarView() {
        if ((this.mProgress != null) && (this.mPalette != null)) {
            this.mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.mPalette.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing dialog in activity:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        final ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog();
        colorPickerDialog.initialize(R.string.dialog_title, new int[]{Color.CYAN, Color.LTGRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW}, Color.YELLOW, 3, 2);
        colorPickerDialog.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onColorSelected(int color) {


                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "selectedColor : " + color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        LinearLayout theme = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.theme);

        theme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                colorPickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "colorpicker");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thank you..

Comment: DID YOU FIND AN ANSWER?